# How to call BI Publisher Report from PL/SQL package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, soapui, bi-publisher

Is it possible to call a BI publisher report from PL/Sql package and dump the data of a BI Publisher report to a oracle database table.

I have earlier used SOAP UI to call the BI Publisher report and dump data in oracle table .

But now I want to call the report from pl/sql package .
Anyone please help
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

You could write a Java class with a static method to do a SOAP call to your BI Publisher service, host that on your database, and use a Stored Procedure to execute the java function.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14187/chthree.htm

You can then use the returned result in Java - create a JDBC connection into a table on your database, and insert the returned file from the SOAP call as a blob.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply !! ..Let me explore the links